# How can I work locally with facebook login with the settings of App Domains and Website with Facebook Login?

Tags: local, facebook-login

I want to set up the facebook login for my website locally but it gives the warning:

```
One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

In the facebook app settings, I set as follows:

```
App Domains:mysite.com
Website with Facebook Login:http://mysite.com
```

Is that OK if I want to work locally? And what else should I do to avoid the warning? And I am quite confused with how the facebook_login works. I am new to this area, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are doing local development and your app hosted locally with url:

```
http://localhost:53750/
```

**Go to your settings on Facebook: Apps-> YOUR_APP_NAME -> Settings -> Add Platform**

[image]

**Select WebSite and enter your url and save changes After that you should have something like:**

[image]

**Done. Try to login from your web app.**